# PyChar does not autocomplete, even does not sees any libraries from Python

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter

I used to work with PyCharm and everythng was ok until now. Now I can not work properly with python interpreter - PyCharm does not see python interpreters and does not see any libraries installed on my system - take a look into a linked picture below.

[PyCharm bug on interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfYuP.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can change local interpreter, for this click the gear, and click "Add Local"; then select the file location of the python in you system